# Checkstyle EmptyLineSeparator not failing on multiple blank lines before class decleration

Tags: checkstyle

Why does Checkstyle not recognise the empty lines after the `import` statement but before the `class` declaration as a violation?

```
package b.pi.persistence.hibernate;

import java.lang.String;



// ^^^ much space! Why is the above not a violation of EmptyLineSeparator   
public class CheckstyleExample {

  ...
}
```

with the following check declared:

```
<module name="EmptyLineSeparator">
  <property name="allowNoEmptyLineBetweenFields" value="true"/>
  <property name="allowMultipleEmptyLines" value="false"/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because lack of testing and issue in code.

Generally this check validates if there is no more than one empty line *above* some tokens. It works well when there are multiple unnecessary spaces above `import` or `package`. When the check reaches `class` declaration it also would validate lines above, but...

- at line [EmptyLineSeparatorCheck.java#L214](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/checkstyle-6.10.1/src/main/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/whitespace/EmptyLineSeparatorCheck.java#L214) next sibling is obtained for `class` token and it is `null`, as there's noting else on the same level as this class in the file
- because next sibling is `null` entire validation is skipped at line [EmptyLineSeparatorCheck.java#L216](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/checkstyle-6.10.1/src/main/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/whitespace/EmptyLineSeparatorCheck.java#L216)

This bug was submitted as [checkstyle/checkstyle#2067](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/2067) and hopefully fix will be realeased in Checkstyle 6.11.

Answer (score 3):

Still not working correctly even with another bugfix on Checkstyle v8.20 regarding this issue: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/5981

I'll now use a simple RegexpMultiline to ensure no multiple empty lines:

```
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="message" value="Multiple empty lines after this line."/>
    <property name="format" value="[\r]?\n\s*[\r]?\n\s*[\r]?\n"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
</module>
```